# Start ember in a specific route

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-router

Im trying integrate emberjs on ruby on rails,

```
https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails

rails generate ember:install --head
```

Ok now emberjs is working, but now how can I for example make emberjs work only on a specific route.

I can do it in rails:

```
root to: static/index
```

Now I want make ember start and work only on posts, cause at the moment when I install the gem only works on application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the opposite a few days back, wanted to serve one page outside of ember.

I created a new namespace in my `router.rb` and a new layout file in my `views/layout/` (`api.html.erb`), which serves as a base for all my non-ember pages. To a big extend it was a copy of my application.html.erb.

You can then specify in the appropriate controllers that they need to make use of the other layout file.

```
class Api::ShareController < ApplicationController
  layout 'api'

  def index
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your code, but this is might what you are searching for:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Router.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('posts');
  }
});
```

this will cause that navigating to the `/` URL of your ember app will immediately transitions to the `/posts` route.

for more information on redirecting in ember you can check out the [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/redirection/)

hope it helps

Comment: The problem persists, I want for example have 10 static pages ( not with emberjs, just ruby rails) then a login page, and one time the users login, they access a campus page that works with emberjs, have no sense the other pages work with ember, so I want start emberjs only on that campus route

Comment: @Nonyck is this maybe something your webserver should manage?

Comment: that is why I put ( and was remove) ruby rails start emberjs on a specific route